# final cut express: import you tube video

Tags: video, youtube, import, final-cut-pro

what is the safest and "virus free" way to import you tube video in final cut express? Is there a way to save "you tube video" as a local file and reuse it in final cut express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Final Cut, I'm assuming that you're on a Mac.

You can save YouTube videos using [YouTube Downloader+](http://download.cnet.com/YouTube-Downloader/3000-2071_4-192611.html) (here's the [PC Version](http://download.cnet.com/YouTube-Downloader/3000-2071_4-10647340.html)). YouTube Downloader saves the videos as FLV (which cannot be imported into Final Cut) so you will need to convert them to QuickTime format using a program such as [Perian](http://www.perian.org/#download).

If Perian doesn't work out, you can find more options for converting FLV [here](http://fcproducer.com/2008/03/flv-in-final-cut-pro/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Have you used these programs? Are they virus free?

Comment: I've only used YouTube Downloader, so I can verify that it is virus free. I haven't used Perian, but the site that it's hosted on looks legitimate.